# What's the best way to make use of the GDPR extension's capabilities via webforms in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, gdpr

I've generally used webforms integrated with CiviCRM on Drupal sites for mailing list sign-ups. Been looking at how to simply link those with the GDPR extension so that the acceptance of privacy policy etc. is logged. Anyone got a slick solution?

Comment: @ added updated code link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a drupal module available here https://github.com/tapashdatta/webform_gdpr/tree/5.x ,